# Remote ElasticSearch cluster azure cloud connection using Python Client using http

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-py

I'am having a trouble to connect the Python API to Elasticsearch.
The Elasticsearch cluster is in azure cloud environment.
This is what I tried:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch(
    "https://machine_name.kb.westeurope.azure.elastic-cloud.com:9200/",
    ca_certs="/path/to/http_ca.crt",
    api_key=("api_id",  "api_key")
)
```

However i can't ping the 'es' client. In fact the test return a None Object.

```
if not es.ping():
    print("No connection")
else:
    print(es.ping())
```

The code abose print "No connection".
Can you please tell me what is wrong with my code ?
There is another method using the Cloud ID. Where i can find the Cloud ID ?

Please Help, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

You are pinging `Kibana`'s domain name not `Elasticsearch`. The domain name is wrong. You should take the `Elasticsearch` domain name.

## To Solve

In your url you need to change `machine_name.kb.westeurope` to `machine_name.es.westeurope`

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch(
    "https://machine_name.es.westeurope.azure.elastic-cloud.com:9200/",
    ca_certs="/path/to/http_ca.crt",
    api_key=("api_id",  "api_key")
)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your anwser. I changed my code but the error still persist.  I would like to use the Cloud Id like this: from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

# Password for the 'elastic' user generated by Elasticsearch
ELASTIC_PASSWORD = "<password>"

# Found in the 'Manage Deployment' page
CLOUD_ID = "deployment-name:dXMtZWFzdDQuZ2Nw..."

# Create the client instance
client = Elasticsearch(
    cloud_id=CLOUD_ID,
    basic_auth=("elastic", ELASTIC_PASSWORD)
)    Where i can find the cloud id ?

Comment: On your https://cloud.elastic.co/home console

Comment: @saad, the cloud id can be found on your cloud.elastic.co console. If you do not have access to the console.. you won't have access to the cloud id